# Chromecast EIA-608 Closed Captions with HLS

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I'm using the [CastCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android) for chromecast sender support in my android application. The receiver application is the default [Styled Media Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/styled_receiver).

My streams are HLS and contain an EIA-608 closed captions track. From the documentation it seems the styled media receiver and CastCompanionLibrary both support EIA-608 closed captions, but I can't seem to get it working.

I am enabling VideoCastManager.FEATURE_CAPTIONS_PREFERENCE when initialising the CastCompanionLibrary, and building the tracks as follows:

```
    MediaTrack videoTrack = new MediaTrack.Builder(0, MediaTrack.TYPE_VIDEO)
            .setContentType(PlayerActivity.HLS_MIME_TYPE)
            .setContentId(playlistUrl)
            .build();

    MediaTrack captionsTrack = new MediaTrack.Builder(1, MediaTrack.TYPE_TEXT)
            .setContentType(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_TEXT_CEA_608)
            .setSubtype(MediaTrack.SUBTYPE_CAPTIONS)
            .setLanguage(Locale.getDefault())
            .setContentId("eia608/1")
            .setName("Closed Captions")
            .build();
```

My guess is that I'm specifying an incorrect contentId, but there doesn't appear to be anything in the docs about contentId for in-band tracks (maybe it's not required)?

I'd appreciate if someone who's gotten this working could chime in ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CEA-608 is supported for HLS (transport stream) by our Media Player Library (MPL) but in order to use that, you need to write a custom receiver and call `enableCaptions(true)` on the player (on the receiver side). I suggest you copy our [reference receiver](https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample) and then make the changes there; that reference receiver is very close to the Styled Receiver. Once you could get the captions working, then you can add a custom message (supported in CCL) to control that from the sender.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It's a shame we have to go through so many hoops just to be able to call a single, library provided method.